# Using configuration.xml file and supplying DataSource settings in MyBatis 3.0.6

Tags: java, configuration, datasource, mybatis

MyBatis documentation shows a way to build a `SqlSessionFactory` through XML configuration file or a `Configuration` object through Java code. It also mentions passing properties that will override what is specified in the XML file.

I am trying use the properties facility to supply a data source URL in addition to the XML configuration, but the property does not get set.

Here's the configuration XML I am using (removed all the aliases and mappings for brevity):

```
<configuration> 
  <typeAliases>
    <typeAlias alias="Item" type="com.example.project.Item"/> 
  </typeAliases>

  <environments default="development"> 
      <environment id="development"> 
      <transactionManager type="JDBC"/> 
      <dataSource type="POOLED"> 
        <property name="driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/> 
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:C:/path_to_db_file_in_the_filesystem"/>   
        <property name="username" value="sa"/> 
        <property name="password" value="sa"/>     
      </dataSource> 
    </environment> 
  </environments> 

  <mappers> 
    <mapper resource="com/example/project/mappers/ItemMapper.xml"/> 
  </mappers>

</configuration>
```

The XML file works fine for everything, but I need to supply the `url` through Java code (through the code, it is obtained from another configuration file so it has to be dynamically supplied to MyBatis). I know I can do it all in code, but that will be unnecessary work so I would like to avoid that route if possible.

Based on the description in the manual, I removed the `url` line from the XML file and came up with the following code:

```
String resource = "com/example/project/MyBatisConfiguration.xml"; 
Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource); 

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("url", url);
SqlSessionFactory ssf = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader, props);
```

The code builds the `SqlSessionFactory`, but I get the "url cannot be null" exception, indicating that the property was not successfully overwritten. I think the name of the property should be in a special format, but I could not find out what that format is.

Thanks a lot in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your configuration XML you can insert a placeholder for the datasource URL like that:

```
<property name="url" value="${url}"/>
```

Then the `build()` method  of `SqlSessionFactoryBuilder` replaces `"${url}"` in the XML with the value of property `"url"` provided by `props`.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get by changing two things at the same time. I had the placeholders, but I tried to fill them using values from a .properties file. When that did not work, I removed the placeholders and tried to pass the properties in. Not very smart, is it? :-)

Comment: Hehe, that's life. It doesn't mean you're not smart. Sometimes there is a need for another pair of eyes looking at the problem.